# How to Use Images Instead Of Drawing Primitives

Tags: 2d, tiles

I want to build backgammon game. I have successfully built the board using primitives  such as lines, triangles and circles. I'm curious whether it's possible to draw the board using images which will make the board look much nicer. Is it possible to have images of triangle and then to put on top of it tiles? How is this achieved?

For example, let's say I have 100x80 image of a triangle and a 100x20 tile image of tile. What theoretically needs to be done in order for the tile image to be shown on top of the triangle image? (each have different colors, and the width of both is the same).

P.S 
I'm currently programming this in Objective C for the iOS, but I don't think it's important, as this is more of a general question.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Essentially this would be done by drawing a rectangle and applying a texture of your game board to it.

Comment: what do you mean applying texture?

Comment: You should use cocos2d and read a tutorial. If you follow this advise you WILL save a lot of time. Unless this is a learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it's simply a matter of the pictures you use. It turns out that .png files have no background which means you can create layers. I created such files using Pixelmator and here is a quick tutorial on the subject:
http://www.pixelmator.com/tutorials/quickly-remove-unwanted-background/

I'm developing for the iphone so if anyone is interested, I used UIImageView and added subview to the master UIImageView and it works very nicely.